# How to find specific script with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to look on my html file and to found if specific script is exist.

I wrote this code :

```
var scriptExist = false;
$('script').each(function(i,e){                 
if( $(e).attr('src')){
if( $(e).attr('src').search("load.js)!=-1){    
scriptExist = true;
return false;
}            
}
 });
 return scriptExist;                    
},
```

it is possible to do this lofic in jQuery without to use.each and to found the specific script for example src = load.js ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$('script').filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr('src') === "load.js"
})
```

or you can use  [`attribute contains selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.

```
$('script[src*="load.js"]')
```

Comment: what the meaning of .bar() ? hut to call to function bar()

Comment: @user1365697 there is nor bar() method, you can replace it with other jQuery methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
var $script = $("script[src='load.js']");
var scriptExists = $script.length > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var script = $("script[src='load.js']");
if (script.length>0)
alert("exists")
```